# PHP socket functions - considerations when moving from Linux to Windows?

Tags: php, sockets, cross-platform, winsock

I have a PHP websocket server, written using the socket module (`socket_bind()`, `socket_accept()`, `socket_recv()`, etc.).

It was written and tested and is working well on Linux.  However, the implementation needs to be cross-platform.

I have done a quick test running it on Windows, and there were no immediate errors, but I would like a bit more certainty that my implementation is sound rather than just assuming it is OK because I haven't yet spotted any errors (which would be the case even after more in-depth testing, as sockets have a lot of edge-cases).

To what extent do these PHP functions abstract the underlying architecture (Unix sockets vs. Winsock)?  For example,

- Are there differences in the effect/availability of various flags or options?
- Do the error codes differ, and if so is there a way of mapping them across?
- Are there architectural differences that mean similar functions may behave differently (e.g. different rules about blocking)?

I'm not looking for a specific analysis of my code, as there is far too much of it, but more for a general idea of what differences I need to be aware of in order to make this code portable.

Note that, for the purposes of this question, I am only really interested in TCP/IP sockets (though more general answers are also fine).

Comment: This is what your integration tests are for...

Comment: That was my point about 'even after more in-depth testing'.  Integration tests cover standard operation and easy-to-generate errors, but it's a lot harder to test the edge-cases, e.g. from a badly behaving client or a slow connection, and these are the most likely places where variance will occur.

Comment: That certainly is true. But following an agile procedure one would tackle such issues when they arise.

Comment: We can't take it to production on that basis.

Comment: Why not? There is no procedure in the world that offers absolute certainty on such questions. Actually one of the main successful ideas behind agile progress is to enter production for each step as soon and as often as possible to gain feedback. Why would one want to slow that process down?

Comment: This conversation is tangential to the question being asked, and is not particularly constructive.